# Wildcard index followed by a number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to rename a lot of files with mmv. I know how to do that but I have a problem with wildcard indexes followed by numbers in the filename.

Basically I need to have an output filename which contains a wildcard followed by numbers.

```
mmv -n ``\*2\\.3_\*'' ``#11.6#2''
```

Here, as you can see, I'd like to have an output filename which contains the first wildcard followed by 1.6.

Unfortunately, this way I have #11.6 and the code is interpreted as if I want the 11th wildcard, which of course do not exist.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add an example what files you have and how you want them to be renamed. The quotes are wrong you should use `"` or `'`

Comment: I added these quotes because mmv help explcitly asked for them. By the way it doesn't work even with your suggested quotes. This is just an example, my files have much more complex names and they would just be misleading. I just want to know how to make it read #1 followed by 1.6 and not #11 followed by .6

Comment: If you simplified your pattern than you should also be able to show one or two original file names that would match your pattern and how you would have them renamed and what happens instead. This would make the question easier to understand. The wrong quotes might be a typographical problem in the help. The quotes shown in your question are useless. `` substitutes the output of an empty command and `''` quotes an empty string at the end of your argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation you should have been able to find a solution.

Citation from `man mmv`, see https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html

> To strip any character (e.g. ’*’, ’?’, or ’#’) of its special meaning to mmv, as when the actual replacement name must contain the character ’#’, precede the special character with a ´\’ (and enclose the argument in quotes because of the shell). This also works to terminate a wildcard index when it has to be followed by a digit in the filename, e.g. "a#1\1".